# Intra company web hosting solutions with mac mini any suggestions?

Tags: macos, hosting, web-hosting

We have mac mini in our company and I want to host intra website.

Any suggestion for best way to host ?

I tried configuring Apache with OS X Yosemite and didn't work at all. 
[Setting up Apache web server on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487138/setting-up-apache-web-server-on-mac-os-x-10-10-5-yosemite)

After spending a day on this, I had to look for alternatives.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to user SimpleHTTPServer for this purpose.

http://www.andyjamesdavies.com/blog/javascript/simple-http-server-on-mac-os-x-in-seconds